# Can't start postgres with correct data directory after Brew update

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

Brew seems to have installed postgresql@14 again for me at some point. I could not use this to view/edit my data directory so I ran:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql@13
brew services start postgresql@13
```

However, I now have `/usr/local/var/postgres/`, and `/usr/local/var/postgresql@13/`. When I run `psql`, it connects to the data directory at `/usr/local/var/postgresql@13/` which is not where any of my valuable data is stored.

How do I start the postgres server with the previous data directory?

The log file:

```
./~ λ: cat /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@13.log
2023-05-24 20:42:30.593 CDT [22914] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30), 64-bit
2023-05-24 20:42:30.594 CDT [22914] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-24 20:42:30.594 CDT [22914] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-24 20:42:30.595 CDT [22914] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-24 20:42:30.602 CDT [22925] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-04-02 10:08:17 CDT
2023-05-24 20:42:30.612 CDT [22914] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-05-24 20:42:32.047 CDT [22934] FATAL:  database "<my name>" does not exist
2023-05-24 20:42:54.086 CDT [23049] FATAL:  database "<my name>" does not exist
2023-05-24 20:49:25.468 CDT [22914] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2023-05-24 20:49:25.472 CDT [22914] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 22931) exited with exit code 1
2023-05-24 20:49:25.472 CDT [22926] LOG:  shutting down
2023-05-24 20:49:25.482 CDT [22914] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-24 21:05:18.288 CDT [27353] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30), 64-bit
2023-05-24 21:05:18.289 CDT [27353] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-24 21:05:18.290 CDT [27353] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-24 21:05:18.290 CDT [27353] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-24 21:05:18.300 CDT [27362] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-24 20:49:25 CDT
2023-05-24 21:05:18.311 CDT [27353] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-05-24 21:06:45.994 CDT [27458] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "q" at character 1
2023-05-24 21:06:45.994 CDT [27458] STATEMENT:  q
        SHOW data_directory;
2023-05-24 21:06:51.508 CDT [27458] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "qSHOW" at character 1
2023-05-24 21:06:51.508 CDT [27458] STATEMENT:  qSHOW data_directory;
2023-05-24 21:10:16.144 CDT [27353] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2023-05-24 21:10:16.149 CDT [27353] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 27368) exited with exit code 1
2023-05-24 21:10:16.150 CDT [27363] LOG:  shutting down
2023-05-24 21:10:16.164 CDT [27353] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-24 21:11:40.254 CDT [28647] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30), 64-bit
2023-05-24 21:11:40.256 CDT [28647] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-24 21:11:40.256 CDT [28647] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-24 21:11:40.256 CDT [28647] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-05-24 21:11:40.269 CDT [28655] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-05-24 21:10:16 CDT
2023-05-24 21:11:40.292 CDT [28647] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: Check the logs in log dir /usr/local/var/log/postgresql@13, and see what the log say

Comment: The postgres server starts fine, it's just pointing to an empty data directory that doesn't contain my databases